# How to retrieve data from one executeQueryAsync and use it in another executeQueryAsync within the same ClientContext

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I want to add item to list where Title is equal to current user ID by JavaScript Object Model.

As far as I know I first need to get currentUserID and I wrote the following code

```
currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
clientContext.load(currentUser);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
  Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded),
  Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed)
);

function onQuerySucceeded(){
    alert (currentUser.get_id());
}
function onQueryFailed(){
    alert("Fail!" + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());    
}
```

With following piece of code I can add item to the list

```
list = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("MyList");
itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
currentUser = oWebsite.get_currentUser();
istItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
listItem.set_item("Title", "Current SPUser ID"); //here I'd like to write user's ID
now = new Date();
now.format("dd/M/yy h:mm tt");
listItem.set_item("Visit", now);
listItem.update();
userData = clientContext.load(listItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded),
            Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed)
            );

        function onQuerySucceeded() {
            alert("Success");
        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message());
        }
```

What I want is to replace string "Current SPUser ID" with actual user ID (currentUser.get_id()).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place the second code section in a function and call it from the success function of the first passing the userid as a parameter.

Answer (score 5):

It actually depends how to retrieve current `User id`

Suppose we have a function for adding List Item

```
function AddListItem(listTitle,itemProps,OnItemAdded)
{
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();


    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var listItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    for(var propName in itemProps) {
       listItem.set_item(propName, itemProps[propName]) 
    }

    listItem.update();
    context.load(listItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
          OnItemAdded(listItem);           
        },
        function(sender, args) {
           OnItemAdded(null);
        }
    );
}
```

### Retrieve current User Id via CSOM (JavaScipt)

In this case `current user Id` have to be retrieved first

```
function GetCurrentUserId(OnComplete) {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
    context.load(currentUser);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
            var userId = currentUser.get_id();
            OnComplete(userId);
        },
        function(sender, args) {
            OnComplete(null);
        }
    );  
}
```

and only then we can add item as demonstrated below

```
function Insert()
{
    //1
    GetCurrentUserId(function(userId){

        var itemProperties  = {'Title': userId}
        AddListItem('CustomList',itemProperties,function(){});      

    });
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Insert, 'SP.js');
```

### Retrieve current user Id from _spPageContextInfo

```
function Insert()
{
    var userId = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
    var itemProperties  = {'Title': userId}
    AddListItem('CustomList',itemProperties,function(){});
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Insert, 'SP.js');
```

Comment: Your answer clarified some points to me. tks!

Answer (score 1):

First we will load the current user and then use it success method to add list item. Code example below

```
 this.currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
 clientContext.load(currentUser);
 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
 Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded),
Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed)
);

function onQuerySucceeded(){
    alert (currentUser.get_id());
   //add list item code goes here.. Pass current users id as currentUser.get_id()
}
function onQueryFailed(){
   alert("Fail!" + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had to do this very thing yesterday. Firstly you need to create a variable to hold you userID

```
var userID;
```

Then in your document ready function call the sharePointReady function (or whatever you want to call it)

```
$(document).ready(function () { sharePointReady(); }
```

Then the funciton

```
// This function creates a context object which is needed to use the SharePoint object model
function sharePointReady() {
context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
web = context.get_web();

getUserName();
}
```

Then the rest

```
// This function prepares, loads, and then executes a SharePoint query to get the
// current users information
function getUserName() {
user = web.get_currentUser();
context.load(user);
context.executeQueryAsync(onGetUserNameSuccess, onGetUserNameFail);
}

// This function is executed if the above call is successful
// It replaces the contents of the 'helloString' element with the user name
function onGetUserNameSuccess() {
fullUserName = user.get_title();
userID = user.get_id();
$('#message').text('Welcome back ' + fullUserName);
}
```

You see from mine i wanted to store both the Name and the ID for various purposes. Then your insert looks like this...

```
listItem.set_item("Title", fullUserName);
```

Hope this helps.

S